# How to deal with launch4j error

Tags: arduino-uno

It seems that the last several times I've tried to open Arduino IDE I've encountered an error that says Launch4j, "an error occurred while starting the application".  It takes some time before that happens.  I think I've seen some stuff online about this, however I've seen some mixed answers and results for how to solve that problem.  I'm using it on a Windows 7, 64 bit system.  I've tried opening it up while my Arduino was connected and it didn't work.